# Correcting Drift in R Studio

Tags: r, trend

Good Day,

I have a dataset of an IMU (int_os = Angle of Upper Leg) whilst cycling with (almost) the same RPMs, the IMU has a drift (a continuously increasing deviation away from the true position).

[image]
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a package/example on how to correct the drift of a dataset in R.

The end result should be a dataset int_os2 that does not contain the continous deviation (angle of the upper leg should stay the same and not 'drift').
Somewhat liket his:
[image: Result should look something like this]

I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: what do you mean by "how to correct drift" ?

Comment: @utobi How am I able to correct the data so the dirft (a continuously increasing deviation away from the true position) does not ooccur.

Answer (score 0):

You could fit a smoother like loess or rolling mean and take the residuals from the fit (in the case of rolling mean that would be your datapoint minus the rolling mean). This is a simpler example of your data, but with some tweaking of the parameters you should be able to get the expected results:

```
x <- seq(1, 100, length.out=1000)
y <- sin(x) + seq(0, 3, length.out=length(x)) + rnorm(length(x), sd= 0.1)

plot(x, y, type='l', col='grey60')
points(x, y, pch=19)
```

[image]

Fit loess and plot the de-trended residuals:

```
fit <- loess(y ~ x)

plot(x, fit$residuals, type='l', col='grey60')
points(x, fit$residuals, pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer by dariober.
I want to add that sometimes, the drift is not linear. Then, it makes sense to use a rolling mean function, as also suggested.
Also, be aware that filtering data can cause a delay. So a correction might be necessary.